# Which Chachamim or great figures in our tradition got divorced? What is said about these marriages?

Tags: divorce, job-iyov-book-of, suffering

I have read that Abraham gave Hagar a divorce but the source was disreputable and I could not find a reputable one.

The context here is that I am learning Iyov and thinking about the misfortunes that some must bear. The talmud says "Anyone who divorces his first wife - even the Altar sheds tears." (Gittin 90a-b)".

edit: we can ask why Iyov is afflicted/punished by one means but not another. Here I am asking why Iyov was not afflicted/punished by divorce and who was. The first question posed -- who was -- is historic, but it sets up the second question posed (what does the tradition say regarding these marriages) that is certainly Judaic/theological.

Comment: I don't think there ever were any who divorced their wife. Many remarried after their first wife died, but I don't think there's any that just divorced them.

Comment: Tzadok Hakohen of Lublin had a heter meah rabanim: http://hamodia.com/features/day-history-9-elulseptember-4/ -- I once heard that he got advice from a chassidic master not to get the heter meah rabanim, and R' Tzadok attributed his childlesssnes to ignoring that advice.

Comment: Moshe Rabbenu was divorced (some say twice!)

Comment: The seridei esh. The beit halevi. R. Dov schwatzman.

Comment: partial dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22360/759

Comment: Off-topic as about Jews, not Judaism?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:job-iyov-book-of] and [tag:suffering]? You might be discussing Iyov, but the question itself has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @DoubleAA I’d argue that’s a dupe of this much broader question.

Comment: Consider just asking what Judaism view of divorce and or divorced people is.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Being that Iyov is a male, and the man initiates a divorce, how can a man be “punished” with divorce? You can’t force a man into a divorce. And I still don’t see the connection to Avraham’s  divorce of Hagar.

Answer (score 3):

The Biblical source for Abraham divorcing Hagar is [Genesis 21](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0121.htm). The word גָּרֵשׁ (which means divorce in other contexts, such as [Leviticus 21:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0321.htm)). Though some bring an opinion that Abraham remarried Hagar, who was later called Keturah (Rashi on Genesis 25:1).

Moses also divorced his wife Zipporah and took her back ([Exodus 18:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0218.htm)). Again, the word שִלַּח is used for divorce in [Deuteronomy 24:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0524.htm) and [Malachi 2:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2402.htm). This also seems to be how Rashi understands it.

Rabbi Yosi Hagelili is another (post-Biblical) case of divorce, as told in Genesis Rabba 17:3 and Leviticus Rabba 34:14. To quote the story from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jose_the_Galilean):

> Jose's married life was unhappy. His wife was malicious and quarrelsome, and frequently insulted him in the presence of his pupils and friends; on the advice of the latter he divorced her. When she married again and was in straitened circumstances, he was magnanimous enough to support her and her husband.

Comment: ...and then (according to the Midrash) Moshe divorced her again, and she wasn't happy about it.

Comment: How do you see that Rashi understood that Moshe divorced Tziporra?

Comment: @robev The wording is "לכי לבית אביך", which is actually more ambiguous than I remember it when I checked it

Comment: Maybe he meant go to your father's house while I redeem the Jews? And I'll get afterwards?

Comment: @robev Yes, for that reason it might be ambiguous, though some other commentators (e.g. quoted in Ibn Ezra, short version) do explicitly understand it as divorce

Answer (score 3):

The biblical source for Abraham's divorce from Hagar is as cited in the first answer; the traditional source is the Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer (ch. 30) where it is stated that Abraham was instructed by Sara to write a bill of divorce for Hagar and he complied. This is subsequently echoed in Targum Yonatan (Gen. 21:14).

With regards to other great figures, @Ezra , with respect, is wrong. R. Yaakov Loberbaum (author of the 'Netivot Yaakov') was divorced twice, see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29159&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=) & [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29159&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=). I recall [reading or hearing that] R. Elchanan Wasserman too divorced. R. Menashe Klien divorced and remarried sometime later (source: I know the family). If I tried spending more time refreshing my memory I'm certain I can recall other examples.

Additional: [R. Aaron Rokeach](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%97) (previous Belzer Rebbe), [R. Shmuel Salant](http://www.jerusalem-love.co.il/?page_id=2777&skipmobile=true).

Comment: Consider adding sources or links for these assertions.