Did Chazal ever divorce?
I'm wondering, out of pure interest, if we know of any Tannaim, Amoraim, Savoraim, Geonim or Rishonim who divorced their wives?

https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.4b.3

Does the word ופרש in that Gemara for sure mean divorce?

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Ketubot.2.9

@Heshy Are you sure he divorced in that case? Can he not act according to his own position?

Ben Azai divorced the daughter of R' Akiva

@YDJ you have a source?

I saw it in the commentary Leiv Avos by R' Haber on Maseches Avos, Mishna 4:2. It looks like Shmosel is right on the same case. There are a few more references.  I can write it down tonight.

@Gavriel Is there even a halachic disagreement? He just said that his wife was safe, but the beis din was unfortunately not allowed to believe him. Maybe he and his wife could have run away and started fresh in a place where nobody recognized them (since they both knew they were permitted to each other), but other than that the beis din couldn't let them stay together. That was my understanding.

@Heshy There absolutely is a halachic disagreement. If you see the Gemara on that Mishnah, it's clear he did NOT end up divorcing his wife.

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22360/759

Rabbi Yose HaG'lili divorced his wife (Y'rushalmi K'subos 11:3).

In Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer -- his telling his own origin story -- Rabbi Eliezer insists he was not married before he ran off to Jerusalem to study Torah. But in Avos deRabbi Nassan, it mentions by-the-way that he ate at his father-in-law's house. Make of that what you will.

Perhaps they divorced more than what is mentioned in the comments, but there was no need to report this fact in the Sources.  Much of the lives of the Sages is unknown.

You got to imagine R' Tarfon divorced some of his wives https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55134/759

The relevant paragraph in the commentary Leiv Avos by R' Yaakov Haber can be translated as follows:
"When (Ben Azai) was with Rabbi Akiva they said, Kesubos 63a,

The Gemara relates: Rabbi Akiva’s daughter did the same thing (as R' Akiva's wife for R' Akiva) for ben Azzai, who was also a simple person, and she caused him to learn Torah in a similar way, by betrothing herself בצנעה to him and sending him off to study. This explains the folk saying that people say: The ewe follows the ewe; the daughter’s actions are the same as her mother’s.

And they also say in Sota 4b:

The Gemara answers: If you wish, say that he was married and separated from his wife.

And without a doubt he was a great diligent student of the Torah and also entered the PaRDe"S as described later, so he separated completedly from the ways of this world. And when he taught Yebamos 63b

(Regarding anyone who does not engage in the mitzva to be fruitful and multiply) Ben Azzai says: It is (considered) as though he sheds blood and also diminishes the Divine Image, as it is stated: “And you, be fruitful and multiply,” after the verse that alludes to both shedding blood and the Divine Image.
They said to ben Azzai: There is a type of scholar who expounds well and fulfills his own teachings well, and another who fulfills well and does not expound well. But you, who have never married, expound well on the importance of procreation, and yet you do not fulfill well your own teachings. Ben Azzai said to them: What shall I do, as my soul yearns for Torah, and I do not wish to deal with anything else. It is possible for the world to be maintained by others, who are engaged in the mitzva to be fruitful and multiply.

In all likelihood, once he divorced the daughter of R' Akivah his Rabbi, he then separated from her and afterwards complained about it, saying Nedarim 74b, when he overheard the argument of R' Eliezer, R' Akiva, and R' Yehishua regarding husband's or yavam' ability to nullify of vows of a woman:

The baraita adds a comment: Ben Azzai stated his response to hearing this discussion in this language: Woe [ḥaval] to you, ben Azzai, that you did not serve Rabbi Akiva properly.


Again, I see no proof that there was a divorce here, only that he "separated" which does not necessarily mean divorce.
